# Better JQueryish way or CSS sprites

Tags: jquery, image, css-sprites, menubar, mouseclick-event

I have a horizontal menu of five images. All of these 5 images have active and grayed state. When a particular image is active the rest 4 need to be grayed out. Similarly for the other images.

I did it in jquery and that too the code is not so optimized and good. It is like this

```
    $("document").ready(function(){
  $("#imageidone").click(function() {
         $("#imageidone").attr("src","/path to image_active");
         $("#imageidtwo").attr("src","/path to image_grayed");
         $("#imageidthree").attr("src","/path to image_grayed");
         $("#imageidfour").attr("src","/path to image_grayed");
         $("#imageidfive").attr("src","/path to image_grayed");
   });
      $("#imageidtwo").click(function() {
        $("#imageidone").attr("src","/path to image_grayed");
        $("#imageidtwo").attr("src","/path to image_active");
        $("#imageidthree").attr("src","/path to image_grayed");
        $("#imageidfour").attr("src","/path to image_grayed");
        $("#imageidfive").attr("src","/path to image_grayed"); });
and so on for imageidthree, imageidfour, imageidfive
     });
```

How can I do it in a better way using CSS sprites or a more compact jqueryish way,

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
var all = ['#imageidone', '#imageidtwo', '#imageidthree', '#imageidfour', '#imageidfive'];

$.each(all, function(selector, idx) {
    $(selector).click(function() {
        $(all.join()).attr('src', '/path to image_grayed');

        $(selector).attr('src', '/path to image_active');
    });
});
```

Comment: Is idx an ID here, and how do I call this function, as I need to change the state of 4 images to gray and 1 to active.
your $(all.join()).attr('src', '/path to image_grayed'); has path to only one gray image

Comment: Using sprites will make this code work as well as give you better network performance.

Comment: Do I need to use jquery as well in that case, Actually I am not sure how to add onclick event handlers on sprite images.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it css sprites,

Make a big image with all states and make classes in css and using jquery you can change the class name.

As you always load only one image , performance will be good.

Comment: how do I put click event and change the state of the other 4 images, and how many times do I need to do this?